# Array Java Ljava.lang.String

Tags: java, arrays

So, I want to write a huge X with the elements of an array in Java:

```
X00000X
0X000X0
00X0X00
000X000
00X0X00
0X000X0
X00000X
```

I keep having the same result: `Ljava.lang.String;@<randomNumbersAndLetters>`

```
package ejercicios;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class FigurasConArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 8;
        String[][] myArr = new String[n][n]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < myArr.length ; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
                myArr[i][j] = "0";
                if (i == j || i == myArr.length - 1) {
                    myArr[i][j] = "x";  
                }
            }   
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArr));
    }
}
```

Comment: The random numbers and letters are the hashcode of the inner arrays in hexdec. `Arrays.toString(...)` does not work since `myArr` is an array of arrays. I would recommend using `Arrays.deepToString(...)`.

Comment: You were abs right. Hands up for you!